# Google sheet API, executing AddProtectedRangeRequest

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

based on: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/ranges

How to execute Google sheet API, executing AddProtectedRangeRequest ?

```
 void addRangeRestriction(final String sheetId, final Sheets sheetService) throws IOException {

    AddProtectedRangeRequest addProtectedRangeRequest = new AddProtectedRangeRequest();


    var gridRange = new GridRange();
        gridRange.setSheetId(1);
        gridRange.setStartColumnIndex(1);
        gridRange.setEndColumnIndex(1);
        gridRange.setStartRowIndex(2);
        gridRange.setEndRowIndex(2);

    var protectedRange = new ProtectedRange();
        protectedRange.setRange(gridRange);
        protectedRange.setWarningOnly(true);

    var request = new Request()
            .setAddProtectedRange(new AddProtectedRangeRequest()
                    .setProtectedRange(new ProtectedRange()
                            .setRange(gridRange)
                            .setRequestingUserCanEdit(false)));


    addProtectedRangeRequest.setProtectedRange(protectedRange);

    // TODO: ... ??
}
```

--

I can do it for

```
   var batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
```

like this:
`return sheetService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(sheetId, batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest).execute();`

but not for AddProtectedRangeRequest or Request.. one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest` accepts a list of requests to execute. You can add your Request to an ArrayList and then assign that to `BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest`.

You can add all the requests that you would like to execute in order in a single `BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest` in this way. Requests will be applied in the order they are specified in the list. If any request is not valid, no requests will be applied.

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
requests.add(request)

var batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.setRequests(requests);

return sheetService.spreadsheets()
    .batchUpdate(sheetId, batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest)
    .execute();
```

Comment: i found that thing happens (it modifies the google sheet file) on
  `batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.setRequests(List.of(request));`
even before the `.execute()`...

Comment: Are you sure? How would that be possible, since you do not specify a `sheetId` until you call `sheetService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(sheetId, batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest).execute();`

Comment: it did happen for another call (for AddSheetRequest, which is outside of the scope of this question i guess) ok..

Comment: the call passed successful. but the thing is: I can not see any difference. I still can edit my my fields (by specified column index row index) in google sheet. was expecting to see that the row-columns are "protected" from change.

Comment: @ses I suspect the `gridRange.setSheetId(1)` might be causing that problem. Have you tried with `gridRange.setSheetId(sheetId)`.

Comment: ohh got it: the range should not be: 0,0 - i should be 0,1 - different numbers. Thanks @Ma3x